# PyQt5 меняет русские буквы на другие в пути к файлу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, кодировка

Попробовал запустить простое приложение PyQt5,

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = sys.argv
    print(s)

    app = QApplication(s)
```

оно вылетело с ошибкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске с терминала выдало

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\ф\PycharmProjects\qt5py>  python main.py
['main.py']
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\Users\o\PycharmProjects\qt5py\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins"   
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Перепробовал почти все, что есть в интернете по этому поводу. И только потом заметил, что в пути к нужному файлу программа заменила `C:\Users\ф\` на `C:\Users\o\` и поэтому, конечно, не может его найти. Попробовал тоже самое в PyQt6 - отработала как надо, значит что-то изменили. Можно ли это как-то исправить в PyQt5? Система Windows 10, Pycharm, Python 3.11.

Comment: Добавьте метку python-3.

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел неутешительные ответы на мой вопрос [1](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7385) и [2](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-972).
Отрывки цитат после гугл-транслейт:

> Оказывается, проблема не в `Qt` как таковом, а скорее в привязках `PySide` и `PyQt`.
>
> Обе привязки после загрузки генерируют встроенный `:/qt/etc/qt.conf` ресурс, в котором они устанавливают префиксный путь для связанных библиотек `Qt` в зависимости от местоположения пакета `Python`. (И `QLibraryInfo` код ищет этот встроенный ресурс, чтобы заполнить его пути/местоположения).
>
> Проблема в том, что они используют локальную 8-битную кодировку (`QString::toLocal8Bit`) для хранения пути, тогда как реализация `QSettings` в `Qt6` (которая используется для загрузки `qt.conf`) предполагает, что значения находятся в `UTF8`. Таким образом, если путь к пакету содержит символы, отличные от `ASCII`, возвращаемые пути в `QLibraryInfo::path` конечном итоге будут искажены из-за несоответствия кодировки. Это происходит только в `Windows`; в `Linux` и `macOS` `QString::toLocal8Bit` эквивалентно `QString::toUtf8`...

> в `Qt5` предполагаемая кодировка — `Latin1`. Это означает, что `PySide2` и `PyQt5` не могут поддерживать в путях символы, отличные от `ASCII`.

и

> В версии `5.15`. будут работать только символы `Latin1`. В `Qt6` будет работать `UTF-8`.